# Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function

Tags: typescript, constructor, xmlhttprequest

```
export default class Promise extends XMLHttpRequest {
    constructor(url: string, type: string) {
        super();
        config.url = url;
        config.requestType = type;
    }
}
```

Here I created a class promise extending the class `XMLHttpRequest`.
Then I tried to access this class using the given method below.

```
let prom = new Promise('api/200', 'get');
```

On entering the super call the following error appeared

> Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function

Comment: How are you compiling it? Which target?

Comment: currently compiling it to es5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript gives, "Could not find a declaration file for module 'xmlhttprequest'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603854/typescript-gives-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because `XMLHttpRequest` is a hosted object, and they sometimes misbehave when extended.

Luckily though, that changes if you extend it with es6 classes.
When you compile this:

```
class RequestPromise extends XMLHttpRequest {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

To es5 you get:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var RequestPromise = (function (_super) {
    __extends(RequestPromise, _super);
    function RequestPromise() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    return RequestPromise;
}(XMLHttpRequest));
```

But when compiling it with target es6 it will keep the class as is:

```
class RequestPromise extends XMLHttpRequest {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

If you try that it should work just fine

Comment: ya I too found that its working well in es6 format, but for me Iam also targetting IE for my application, so I guess es6 wont do any good for that

Answer (score -1):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) makes sending HTTP requests very easy.  You simply create an instance of the object, open a URL, and send the request.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
```